# How to define a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, definition

> Let T and U be the linear operators on $R^2$ defined by:
>
> $T(x,y)$=$(y,z)$ and $U(x,y)$=$(y, 0)$
>
> Give rules like the ones defining T and U for each of the transformations
> (U+T),UT,TU,$T^2,U^2.$

I would say that U+T is defined by:

(U+T)(x,y)= (2y+x)

But I do now know how would I define the others

Comment: Where does the $z$ come from?

Comment: Please use MathJax.

Comment: In the definition of $T$ I think you meant $T(x,y)=(y,x)$.  Also did you mean $T^2$ not $T2$, which is not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $T(x,y) = (y,x), U(x,y) = (y,0)$ (though that is not what is posted in the question...)

$(U+T)(x,y) = U(x,y) + T(x,y) = (y,x) + (y,0) = (2y,x)$

$UT(x,y) = U(T(x,y)) = U(y,x) = (x,0)\\
T^2(x,y) = T(T(x,y)) = T(y,x) = (x,y)$

I will leave $UT(x,y), U^2(x,y)$ to you.

Alternatively,

$T = \begin{bmatrix} 0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}\\
U = \begin{bmatrix} 0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$

Answer (score 0):

Since any linear transformation can be on a finite-dimensional vector space can be expressed using a matrix, the best would be to express $T$ and $U$ as matrices.

All your composed transformations can then simply be expressed as matrix operations. Adding two transformations is adding the matrices and compositions becomes matrix multiplication.